# Ubuntu doesn't show the sound-symbol

Tags: unity, sound, alsa

It's not that big of a problem, more an annoyance: I wanted to install
some dependencies for a MIDI-Sequencer.

PROBLEM: Now, the symbol for sound-settings in the top-status bar is gone. I'm using UNITY, UBUNTU 16.4, and I don't plan in reinstalling
my distro soon.

Also, sometimes Ubuntu doesn't play sounds. EG: in the sound-settings, when I press the buttons for sound-tests,  nothing really happens (yes, I can hear sounds at all).

I already tried the sound-troubleshooting page.

Comment: What MIDI-Sequencer are you trying to install? What dependencies? Please post the instructions you followed and/or all the steps.

Comment: I think, It was renoise.

Comment: The problem accured on the installation of another sound-system. I don't know which one (it was like three weeks ago)

Comment: If you followed some instructions please post them.

Comment: I really don't remember, sorry :(

Comment: But afterall, I think it wasn't renoise, as it costs something, and I don't think, I ever paid for music-software

Comment: This is a Q&A website, the comments section being there for clarification only. Please EDIT your question and add relevant information as requested. Comments are not for chat. Without info the best I can suggest is to reinstall because troubleshooting this takes longer and a Q&A is not a place for extensive troubleshooting. Try other online resources like Ubuntu Forums but unless you can show what you did, nobody will be able to help.